# Firebase cloud function to create document inside collection throws "return is not valid JSON object"

Tags: javascript, json, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firestore database where I want every user of my flutter app to have a document in a collection called `UserFavourites`. I created a https callable cloud function to check if the user has a document and if they don't create one. This is the cloud function code:

```
exports.createUserFavouritesDocument = functions
    .region("europe-west2")
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
        const uid = data.uid;
        const favouritesRef = admin
            .firestore().collection("UserFavourites").doc(uid);
        return favouritesRef.get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                return {
                    success: true
                };
            } else {
                return favouritesRef.set({
                        Stores: []
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        return {
                            success: true
                        };
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        // throw new functions
                        // .https
                        // .HttpsError("internal", "Error creating document.", error);
                        return {
                            error: "Error creating doc"
                        };
                    });
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            if (error.code === "not-found") {
                return favouritesRef.set({
                        Stores: []
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        return {
                            success: true
                        };
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        // throw new functions
                        // .https
                        // .HttpsError("internal", "Error creating document.", error);
                        return {
                            error: "Error creating document"
                        };
                    });
            } else {
                // throw new functions
                // .https
                // .HttpsError("internal", "Error checking for document.", error);
                return {
                    error: "Error creating document"
                };
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see in the code, I checked if the user has a document in the collection and then if the not-found code is thrown I create a new one. You can also see the commented out error throwing lines that I previously had. Even with the new lines, I received the error message: "*Error: internal Response is not valid JSON object".* The user I'm testing it with, doesn't have a document and when the function is called one is not created.
This is the code that calls the function in the flutter app:

```
void _checkdoc() async {
    try {
        final result = await createUserFavouritesDocument.call( < String, dynamic > {
            'uid': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
        });
        print(result.data);
    }
    on FirebaseFunctionsException
    catch (e) {
        print("error");
        print('Error: ${e.code} ${e.message}');
    } catch (e) {
        print('Error: $e');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I didn't define the region in the flutter code. To fix it I replaced `FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('createUserFavouritesDocument');` with `FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west2').httpsCallable('createUserFavouritesDocument');`